# Raising an Event from the Shell in Prism. Is There a Way to Use a Shared Service? Or Just Use PubSubEvent?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, unity-container, prism

I'm using Unity for Dependency injection under Prism and have a situation where one of my modules is to display a screen saver of sorts when the user is running a test and no input has been received. (The region holding the view for this module displays in front of all other regions.) The idea being if the user goes to the other side of the room while the test is running, they can see a summary of relevant test information. When they interact with the application again, the screen saver will exit and return them to the main display.

Since the Shell is what captures user input, I need to alert the screen saver module to hide the view when the user interacts with the computer.

The screen saver module itself implements a shared service interface in the ViewModel that consists of an Enable() method and a Disable() method. The screen saver is only enabled when a test is running. The modules that run these tests will call Enable/Disable as needed. The ViewModel contains an internal timer that when the Screen Saver is enabled, will trigger the display of the View upon expiration. If the user interacts, the timer will reset (and the View is hidden).

I'd like to keep my application from having a large amount of PubSubEvents when its not necessary to have one. In this case, when the user interacts, I'd like to be able to add a method to the Screen Saver service that the Shell can use to signal the user interaction. However, I don't see how that is possible without a PubSubEvent, since the shell is created before the Screen Saver module, unless I want to use a ServiceLocator or by adding a reference to the Screen Saver project in my Shell, both of which I think are worse options than using the PubSubEvent. Even if I separate the services into their own separate module, and reference that from the Shell/Boostrapper (registering via ConfigureContainer()), that module will still need to somehow be able to communicate to the ViewModel to reset the timer/hide the view.

Am I just overthinking this? Is there some other way I can do this? Or is my initial idea of PubSubEvent the best way. I'm rather new to Prism, so I'm still getting a handle on best practices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot see anything wrong with using the `EventAggregator`, but you can, of course, use a specialized service that does basically the same thing, just only for enabling/disabling the screen saver. Just register that service as a singleton and have it injected wherever needed.

To make things a bit nicer, seperate the active (e.g. `EnableScreenSaver()` and `DisableScreenSaver()`) and passive (e.g. `IsScreenSaverEnabled` property and `ScreenSaverStateChanged` event) members into two different interfaces, implemented by the same service. This way you get a little bit of advantage over the `EventAggregator` - events cannot be publish-only or subscribe-only, whoever knows the event can always publish *and* subscribe. But you can make the active interface known only to the parts of your app that want to control the screen saver, whereas the passive interface can be only known the parts that have a screen saver that needs to be controlled...

Comment: How do I inject it into the Shell, though, since the Shell gets created before the service? Even if I include a reference to this service in the Shell project so the Bootstrapper can register it, this service still needs to let the screen saver module know that it should hide its view and reset the timer when the user moves the mouse or types on the keyboard. Adding an event to the service which the Screen Saver subscribes to doesn't make much sense because that event will fire from some indication from the shell to that service in which case the PubSubEvent is a much cleaner solution.

Comment: If you register the service from the bootstrapper (i.e. `ConfigureContainer`), it will be available when the shell is resolved. Other than that, as stated above, `EventAggregator`/`PubSubEvent` is perfectly valid...

Comment: I know about the ConfigureContainer thing. What I wasn't understanding was that the service would have two interfaces, one registered by the bootstrapper and one registered by the service module. The former will allow the shell to indicate that user interaction has occurred. The latter will hold the event that the ViewModel tied to the screen saver can subscribe to. (And that interface will be injected into the constructor of the ViewModel.) But with figuring this out, I think the PubSubEvent is a far simpler option since using a multiply interfaced shared service seems a bit tortured. Thanks!